# How do I extract the month number from a date and return the month name?

Tags: excel, vba

I have table which contains a column of dates in the following format: m/d/yyyy. Below is a picture, which shows the dates in column C:

[image]

Goal: I would like to know how to create a function in VBA that extracts the month number from the dates in column C and return the month name in column E, like shown in the picture below:

[image]

I can enter the month names manually by looking in column C, but I was wondering if there is a function that can do this task automatically.

Comment: Is the "Date of Operation" column formatted as a string or a date?

Comment: It is formatted as a date. @Taelsin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup, [TEXT()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c) will do it:

```
=TEXT(C2,"mmmm")
```

[image]

Comment: I guess I don't need to do this in VBA after all! This seems easier than I thought. Thanks! @Scott Craner

Comment: @NickRivera If you really want vba: `Range("E2") = Format(Range("C2"),"mmmm")`